# Ubuntu 22.04 does not work on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: 22.04, raspberrypi, sd-card

I am having trouble installing Ubuntu 22.04 on my Raspberry Pi 4 8 GB. I have a SanDisk Extreme 64 GB microSD on which I previously had Ubuntu 20.04 installed and it worked.

Now I am trying to install 22.04 by putting the microSD with an adapter in a Windows PC and using Raspberry Pi Imager v1.7.2, I'm following the steps on the official page, but when I put the microSD in the Raspberry it turns off and does not start the operating system.

I've also tried installing to a USB and booting Ubuntu 22.04 from there, but the Raspberry also shuts down. Installing other operating systems the same way works fine. I redownloaded the 20.04.4 image and putting the microSD into the Raspberry works fine.

How can I make Ubuntu 22.04 work on Raspberry Pi 4?

Comment: Just for fun, did you try installing 20.04.4 and then upgrading to 22.04 (using `do-release-upgrade`) - might be a solution for you. 

Comment: I just wonder if there’s a problem with the Ubuntu 22.04 iso you downloaded? As you’ve also put the iso on a usb, could you ‘Try Ubuntu’ in your windows pc using that usb to check it is working?

Answer (score 1):

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 on my Pi 4B 8G with no problem at all! BTW, my Ubuntu consists of both the server and the desktop: my installation procedure:

1. install the server first with Pi-Imager,
2. `sudo apt update`,
3. `sudo full-upgrade`,
4. install g++, gfortran, etc (command line packages that you need),
5. `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`.

I hope this will work for you.